# Can't compile bibtex bibliography with non-default sort technique

Tags: biblatex, books

Using the elegantbook template,
a minimum version of my document looks like this:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass[bibend=bibtex, lang=en, onecolumn, a4, 12pt]{elegantbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{biblatex}
%\usepackage{parskip}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}

\addtolength{\cftchapnumwidth}{40pt}

\begin{document}



\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter



\chapter{Introduction}

Blah blah blah \cite{en1}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title=\ebibname]

\end{document}
```

But if I change the bibliography sort technique via:

```
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
```

I get the following error:

```
Option clash for package biblatex. \addbibresource
```

Doesn't seem to matter where I put the sorting option (in addbibresource for example), it won't work. But the documentation says this should work - where am I wrong here?

ps. This is the canonical way of doing bibliographies using the elegantbook template. I can't seem to do it using \bibliography etcetera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `elegantbook` already loads `biblatex` for you, but *it* only allows you to use three of its many options. You can pass the `backend`, `bibstyle` and `citestyle` options to your class and have them forwarded to `biblatex`, but nothing more. (Personally, I don't think it makes a lot of sense to have a generic document class enforce a particular bibliography package, especially if it adds no further customisations based on that package.)

You cannot load `biblatex` a second time with options that do not match the options that the document class set. So just adding `\usepackage[backend=bibtex, sorting=none]{biblatex}` or some such will fail.

You can use `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions` in your preamble to set the sorting. While not all `biblatex` options are available via this command, most are and `sorting=none,` will work.

```
\documentclass[bibend=bibtex, bibstyle=numeric,]{elegantbook}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{sorting=none} 

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

Lorem \cite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{worman}
dolor \autocite{geer}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title=\ebibname]
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [1] ipsum [2] dolor [3]]

[image: Bibliography section]

---

If you don't want to use `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions` or want to set an option that is not available via that command, you can abuse the `bibstyle` document class option and try to also pass the `sorting` option to `biblatex`  by adding a few curly braces. At the moment this works due to the way the class is coded. (But I don't think this is the intended interface. You may want to get in touch with the class author and discuss your use case with them if that becomes relevant.)

```
\documentclass[bibend=bibtex, bibstyle={numeric, sorting=none,},]{elegantbook}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

Lorem \cite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{worman}
dolor \autocite{geer}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title=\ebibname]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very thorough explanation - thanks, and happy new year!